# How can I generate a multiple period DASH manifest with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I am looking to encode a file and generate multiple periods rather than just one period. When I try to run ffmpeg with the below command, the result is a single period with multiple adaptation sets so clearly that is the wrong approach. I had thought by breaking the files by time this might work but apparently not. Any advice would be appreciated:

```
  ffmpeg -i ~/Downloads/turkish-horses.mp4 \
  -map 0:v:0 -b:v:1 1000k -ss 0 -t 5 -c:v:1 libx264 -filter:v:1 "scale=640:-1"  \
  -map 0:v:0 -b:v:2 1000k -ss 5 -c:v:2 libx264 -filter:v:2 "scale=640:-1"  \
  -map 0:v:0 -b:v:3 3000k -ss 0 -t 5 -c:v:3 libx264 -filter:v:3 "scale=1280:-1" \
  -map 0:v:0 -b:v:4 3000k -ss 5 -c:v:4 libx264 -filter:v:4 "scale=1280:-1" \
  -map 0:a\?:0 -ss 0 -t 5 -c:a aac -b:a 192k \
  -map 0:a\?:0 -ss 5 -c:a aac -b:a 192k \
  -use_timeline 1 -use_template 0 \
  -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=0,2  id=1,streams=4 id=2,streams=1,3 id=3,streams=5" \
  -f dash output.mpd
```

Comment: Hello. i am also in search of the solution of this question. did you get any solution ?